# Convert Integer value into Hour value (AM / PM) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a `table` with hour `values`. I need to convert the hour value into `AM/PM` format, as shown here:

```
val   hour 
---------------
 9     9:00 AM
19     7:00 PM
10    10:00 AM
19     7:00 PM
14     2:00 PM
```

I have tried this logic:

```
declare @timing varchar(5)='15:02'

declare @time time=cast(@timing as time)
select convert(varchar(50),@time, 100)
```

But this requires `val` to be converted into `varchar`. Is there any other way or inbuilt function available in SQL Server to do this?

Comment: What does "*convert*" mean here? Replace in the database or format in query output?

Comment: which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes the output needs to be in AM/PM format

Comment: @SankarRaj Sql server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(hh,val,'00:00:00'),'hh:mm tt') 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: `FORMAT` is only available on SQL Server 2012 and above.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(val,0,0,0,0)
  FROM [table];
```

Comment: I would note that the `TIMEFROMPARTS` function is only available on SQL 2012 and Higher.

Comment: Didn't find any information concerning the used version in the question - therefore I took the best case. ;-) Anyways, if NOT in 2012, I guess there is no way around the convert to varchar.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong - just making sure that the OP knows what versions it applies to.

Comment: it gives output : 15:00:00  if i pass 15 as value

Comment: Yes, hour: minute: second

Comment: I want 09:00 from 8 then how to do??

Comment: @rinkuchoudhary What do you mean with "09:00 from 8"?

Comment: sorry by mistake typed... I mean to say that I have an integer value that is 9 and I want to display it like 09:00 then how to do it??

Comment: Try the following:  SELECT LEFT(TIMEFROMPARTS(9,0,0,0,0),5)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
declare @timing varchar(5)='14'

declare @time time=cast(case when CHARINDEX(':',@timing)=0 then @timing + ':00' else @timing end as time)
select convert(varchar(50),@time, 100)
```

Or

```
Select convert(varchar(50),cast(Cast(val as varchar) + ':00' as time),100) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

`select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST( cast(@val as nvarchar) + ':00:00.0000000' AS TIME),100)`

Answer (score 1):

If it is complex then you can create a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_StringHourToAmPm (@timing VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN        

    DECLARE @time TIME = CAST(@timing AS TIME)
    DECLARE @Output NVARCHAR(50)
    select @Output = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@time, 100)

    RETURN @Output
END
```

Then

```
SELECT dbo.fn_StringHourToAmPm('15:02') -- 3:02PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using FORMAT, this should work on SQL Server 2008 and beyond:

```sql
declare @T table (val int);

insert into @T values (0),(9),(12),(19);

select val, 
replace(convert(varchar, CAST(CONCAT(val%24,':00') as time), 109),':00.0000000',' ') as [hour] 
from @T;
```

Basically, cast the INT to a VARCHAR in the 109 predefined format and clean that up.

Or via using FORMAT after transforming the INT to a DATETIME:

```
select val, FORMAT(DATEADD(HH,val%24,0),'h:mm tt') as [hour] from @T;
```

Both methods will return:

```
val hour
0   12:00 AM
9   9:00 AM
12  12:00 PM
19  7:00 PM
```

Note that the modulus (`val%24`) was added. That's just to make it also work for hours above 23.